# Disabling / moving pop up notifications in teams

Tags: office-365, outlook, microsoft-teams

In Teams (Windows 10), when I get a new chat message, a notification pops up in the bottom right. However, the chat text box and send button is also in the bottom right. So the notification is always over top of it and prevents me from sending chat messages:

[image]

As a consequence, I can't talk to people while other people are talking to me.

Can I either move this notification somewhere else or disable it completely?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out this was a different problem and the notifications weren't coming from Teams itself, but I figure I'll answer myself anyways in case anybody else gets confused.

So I also normally keep the Outlook (Office 365) Mail web site open on this machine, and as it turns out, those were messages that Outlook was sending in response to chats on Teams.

Turning them off was an Outlook configuration option:

1. In the Outlook site, click the gear in the top right.
2. Click "View All Outlook Settings"
3. Go to "General" then "Notifications"
4. Scroll down to the bottom and under "Chat" pick "Do nothing"

Now the Teams app and the Mail web site will play nice together.